# .NET Core - build/package for net451 on Linux (Travis CI)

Tags: travis-ci, .net-core

I have a (private) Github/Travis CI setup and am trying to validate PRs and publish NuGet packages on a release branch.

Here's my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: csharp
os: linux
dist: trusty
sudo: required
env: DOTNETCORE=1
dotnet: 1.0.0-preview2-003121
mono: none
before_script:
  - npm install
script:
  - gulp restore && gulp build && if [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH = 'v0.2' ]; then gulp package; fi
```

I'm using gulp to do some additional logic and build steps, but basically it invokes everything correctly.. the relevant invocations it does are:

`dotnet restore`

`dotnet build **/project.json`

The former succeeds, the latter fails for projects which target `net451`.  Errors look like it can't find framework assemblies, which makes sense, though I'm not sure on the best approach to resolve:

`/home/travis/build/Secret/secret/src/Secret.Sample/project.json(7,52): error NU1001: The dependency mscorlib could not be resolved.`

(same many times over, also for `System`, `System.Core`, `System.Xml`...)

Here's a sample `project.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0-*",
    "description": "Description..",
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0-alpha1-22107",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0-alpha1-22107",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0-alpha1-22107",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.1.0-alpha1-22107",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "1.1.0-alpha1-22107",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0-alpha1-22107",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0-alpha1-22107",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0-alpha1-22107",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0-alpha1-22107"
  },
    "frameworks": {
        "netstandard1.6": {
        },
        "net451": {
            "buildOptions": {
                "define": [ "SAMPLEY_ON_WINDOWS" ]
            },
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog": "1.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1090, where David F indicates "You can't build .NET Framework apps using CoreCLR today." (Nov 2015).  Is that stil true, and it's as simple as that? - in which case I should use have Travis just build/test, skipping `net451`, and Appveyor for build,test and deploy to NuGet?

That wouldn't be my first choice, but if so, how could I optionally tell `dotnet build` to skip unsupported framework targets?

Ideally, I just need to re-jig my dependencies, or understand `frameworkAssemblies`, or `apt-get` something else into the build environment..?

Comment: Have found https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9735#issuecomment-229196479 .. will update if I can use this info to solve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To target .NET Framework targets e.g. `net451` in Travis, you need Mono installed.

I fixed by changing `mono: none` to `mono: 4.0.5`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can tell `dotnet build` and `dotnet test` to skip over unsupported framework targets by using the `-f` parameter, and putting in the frameworks that you *do* want to compile. For example, to compile `net451` exclusively, you can run `dotnet build -f 451`.
2. Consider using the `latest` version for mono in your `.travis.yml` file if you want to ensure you are compatible with the latest release of mono instead of a specific version. That desire depends on your requirements.
3. You can absolutely build your application for .NET Core on your local box and in Travis CI, yet use it on a .NET Framework application. However, you have to dance around the ".NET Platform Standard" concepts. For using that .NET Core application as a dependency in a traditional .NET Framework application, the .NET Core application would have to be built for .NET Platform Standard 1.X (as you have done with 1.6), which aligns to some version of .NET Framework 4.X.X. See [this table](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms) to get thoroughly confused on cross operating system compatibility. However, since 4.6.3 is not yet released, you would not yet be able to build a .NET Standard 1.6 library and depend on it in a traditional .NET Framework application. However, you could write your code such that it is compatible with a lower version of the .NET Platform Standard (1.5, 1.4, etc), which are all still compatible with .NET Core, then use that library as a dependency for a released version of a traditional .NET Framework application.

If you'd like to see an example, [here](https://github.com/invio/Invio.Extensions.DependencyInjection) is a github repository with [a `.travis.yml` configuration file](https://github.com/invio/Invio.Extensions.DependencyInjection/blob/master/.travis.yml) that builds in .NET Core & Mono on Travis CI for both Linux and Mac OSX, and .NET Core & .NET Framework on Appveyor for Windows.